# append subprocess.Popen output to file?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I can successfully redirect my output to a file, however this appears to overwrite the file's existing data:

```
import subprocess
outfile = open('test','w') #same with "w" or "a" as opening mode
outfile.write('Hello')
subprocess.Popen('ls',stdout=outfile)
```

will remove the `'Hello'` line from the file.

I guess a workaround is to store the output elsewhere as a string or something (it won't be too long), and append this manually with `outfile.write(thestring)` - but I was wondering if I am missing something within the module that facilitates this.

Comment: This is a deeper issue on Windows and append mode, see https://bugs.python.org/issue45237 for workarounds.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You sure can append the output of `subprocess.Popen` to a file, and I make a daily use of it. Here's how I do it:

```
log = open('some file.txt', 'a')  # so that data written to it will be appended
c = subprocess.Popen(['dir', '/p'], stdout=log, stderr=log, shell=True)
```

(of course, this is a dummy example, I'm not using `subprocess` to list files...)

By the way, other objects behaving like file (with `write()` method in particular) could replace this `log` item, so you can buffer the output, and do whatever you want with it (write to file, display, etc) [but this seems not so easy, see my comment below].

Note: what may be misleading, is the fact that `subprocess`, for some reason I don't understand, will write *before* what you want to write. So, here's the way to use this:

```
log = open('some file.txt', 'a')
log.write('some text, as header of the file\n')
log.flush()  # <-- here's something not to forget!
c = subprocess.Popen(['dir', '/p'], stdout=log, stderr=log, shell=True)
```

So the hint is: do not forget to `flush` the output!

Comment: Note on the above post: after some trials, it seems that `subprocess.Popen` needs something really like a file for its `stdout` and `stderr`arguments, so giving to them a custom object with only a `write` method is not sufficient. I tried, but a `fileno` function is required, and I'm not good enough to emulate this on a class of my own.

Comment: I have been attempting to use this method but I have discovered that for some reason, each time I run the external process with a file which I have definitely opened for appending, the output of the process writes from the beginning of the file and overwrites any information there. So, in order to use this solution, one must call log.seek( 0, os.SEEK_END ) immediately after opening the file.

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem is if you want the header to be header, then you need to flush before the rest of the output is written to file  :D

Answer (score 0):

Are data in file really overwritten? On my Linux host I have the following behavior:
1) your code execution in the separate directory gets:

```
$ cat test
test
test.py
test.py~
Hello
```

2) if I add `outfile.flush()` after `outfile.write('Hello')`, results is slightly different:

```
$ cat test
Hello
test
test.py
test.py~
```

But output file has `Hello` in both cases. Without explicit `flush()` call stdout buffer will be flushed when python process is terminated. 
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and resolved it with the code below

```
      with open("outfile.log", 'w') as f: # use 'a' if you need to append
            subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-la'], shell=False,
                             stdout=f.fileno(),
                             stderr=f.fileno())
```

Greetings