# How to run windows command line from python script?

Tags: python, windows

I have a script in Python which gives a few files but I also need a log file. Usually I use this command in windows cmd:

```
py name.py > name.log
```

This script is part of a project and I need to run it from python. I tried this:

```
subprocess.call(["py","name.py",">","name.log"])
```

And it give me all the files that the script prepares but not the log file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [append subprocess.Popen output to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389158/append-subprocess-popen-output-to-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `os.system`

```
os.system("py name.py > name.log")
```

Or, you can just pass an open file handle for the stdout argument to `subprocess.call`:

```
args = ['name.py']
cmd = ['py'] + args
with open('name.log', "w") as outfile:
    subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=outfile)
```

Comment: Note that when writing to a file or pipe, Windows Python uses the system ANSI codepage by default, which may result in encoding errors. You can override the encoding of standard I/O to UTF-8, e.g. `environ = os.environ.copy();` `environ['PYTHONIOENCODING'] = 'utf-8';` `subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=outfile, env=environ)`.